# Fisher Yates algorithm gives back same order of numbers in parallel started programs when seeded over the system time

Tags: c, algorithm, random, parallel-processing

I start several C / C++ programs in parallel, which rely on random numbers. Fairly new to this topic, I heard that the seed should be done over the time.

Furthermore, I use the Fisher Yates Algorithm to get a list with unique random shuffled values. However, starting the program twice in parallel gives back the same results for both lists.

How can I fix this? Can I use a different, but still relient seed?

My simple test code for this looks like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <time.h>
static int rand_int(int n) {

        int limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
        int rnd;

        do {
                rnd = rand();
        }
        while (rnd >= limit);
        return rnd % n;
}


void shuffle(int *array, int n) {

        int i, j, tmp;
        for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                j = rand_int(i + 1);
                tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
        }
}


int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

        srand(time(NULL));
        int x = 100;
        int randvals[100];
        for(int i =0; i < x;i++)
                randvals[i] = i;

        shuffle(randvals,x);
        for(int i=0;i < x;i++)
                printf("%d %d \n",i,randvals[i]);

}
```

I used the implementation for the fisher yates algorithm from here:

http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-implement-fisher-yates-algorithm-array-shuffling/

I started the programs in parallel like this:

```
./randomprogram >> a.txt & ./randomprogram >> b.txt
```

and then compared both text files, which had the same content.

The end application is for data augmentation in the deep learning field. The machine runs Ubuntu 16.04 with C++11.

Comment: The time is not a good seed because it's predictable and because of the situation you've documented.

Comment: Seeding parallel run programs at the same moment from `time()` is likely to be the same.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: If two programs are started in the same second, they'll both have the same sequence of random numbers.  Use `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` to get some random bytes for the seed.  And consider whether you need to use a better random number generator than the `rand()`/`srand()` duo — that is usually only barely random (better than nothing, but not by a large margin).  Do *NOT* use them for cryptography.

Comment: Luckily it is not for crypthography, but for data processing, so it should be fine

Comment: Which platforms must the code work on?  How random does the randomness need to be?  On many Unix-like platforms, there's a device `/dev/random` — on Linux, there's also a slightly lower-quality device `/dev/urandom`, which is also present on macOS (BSD) as a synonym for `/dev/random`.  You can open it and read 4 bytes of random data, and use that as a seed for the PRNG of your choice.  I often use the [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html)
set of functions because they are in POSIX and were in System V Unix. They're usually adequate for my needs.

Comment: [This](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/cc289c9e6344a3d6386f2ed69849186df75de054:/util.c#l4550) is what `perl` uses.

Comment: For non-cryptographic stuff, I often use some variant of [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) -- Xorshift* being a long-time favourite -- seeded from `/dev/urandom`. The only thing to be aware of is to not use zero as a seed; any other 64-bit unsigned integer works.

Comment: Tank you for your comments, I added the description for what the algortihm is need and on which machine.

Comment: Look at the manuals across platforms; there are often other random number generators.  C++11 provides high-quality PRNG — the header `<random>` has some high quality PRNG, such as the MT 19937 (Mersenne Twister).  MacOS Sierra (BSD) has `random(3)` and `arc4random(3)` as alternatives to `rand()` – as well as `drand48()` et al.

Comment: Another possibility on Linux is simply to keep a connection to `/dev/urandom` open, reading more bytes when you need them.  However, that gives up any chance of replaying a random sequence.  The PRNG systems have the merit of allowing you to replay the same sequence again by recording and setting the random seed that you use.  By default, grab a seed from `/dev/urandom`, but if the user requests it, take a seed from the command line, and report the seed used (at least on request).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the same results due to how you're seeding the RNG:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

The `time` function returns the time in seconds since the epoch.  If two instances of the program start during the same second (which is likely if start them in quick succession) then both will use the same seed and get the same set of random values.

You need to add more entropy to your seed.  A simple way of doing this is to bitwise-XOR the process ID with the time:

```
srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid());
```

Comment: The other problem with using `time` is its predictability. `getpid` only makes it harder to predict for a caller outside of the machine. It also doesn't add that much entropy (16 bits to observers outside of the machine, but only a couple of bits to same-machine observers).  `time(NULL) ^ getpid()` is still a very poor solution.

Comment: time and pids both increment by one slowly, so you might still get collisions. Lower the odds with this: `srand(clock() ^ getpid());`

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment, I like to use a [Xorshift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2A) pseudo-random number generator, seeded from `/dev/urandom` if present, otherwise using POSIX.1 `clock_gettime()` and `getpid()` to seed the generator.

It is good enough for most statistical work, but obviously not for any kind of security or cryptographic purposes.

Consider the following **xorshift64.h** inline implementation:

```
#ifndef   XORSHIFT64_H
#define   XORSHIFT64_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef  SEED_SOURCE
#define  SEED_SOURCE  "/dev/urandom"
#endif

typedef struct {
    uint64_t    state[1];
} prng_state;

/* Mixes state by generating 'rounds' pseudorandom numbers,
   but does not store them anywhere. This is often done
   to ensure a well-mixed state after seeding the generator.
*/
static inline void prng_skip(prng_state *prng, size_t rounds)
{
    uint64_t state = prng->state[0];
    while (rounds-->0) {
        state ^= state >> 12;
        state ^= state << 25;
        state ^= state >> 27;
    }
    prng->state[0] = state;
}

/* Returns an uniform pseudorandom number between 0 and 2**64-1, inclusive.
*/
static inline uint64_t prng_u64(prng_state *prng)
{
    uint64_t state = prng->state[0];
    state ^= state >> 12;
    state ^= state << 25;
    state ^= state >> 27;
    prng->state[0] = state;
    return state * UINT64_C(2685821657736338717);
}

/* Returns an uniform pseudorandom number [0, 1), excluding 1.
   This carefully avoids the (2**64-1)/2**64 bias on 0,
   but assumes that the double type has at most 63 bits of
   precision in the mantissa.
*/
static inline double prng_one(prng_state *prng)
{
    uint64_t u;
    double   d;
    do {
        do {
            u = prng_u64(prng);
        } while (!u);
        d = (double)(u - 1u) / 18446744073709551616.0;
    } while (d == 1.0);
    return d;
}

/* Returns an uniform pseudorandom number (-1, 1), excluding -1 and +1.
   This carefully avoids the (2**64-1)/2**64 bias on 0,
   but assumes that the double type has at most 63 bits of
   precision in the mantissa.
*/
static inline double prng_delta(prng_state *prng)
{
    uint64_t u;
    double   d;
    do {
        do {
            u = prng_u64(prng);
        } while (!u);
        d = ((double)(u - 1u) - 9223372036854775808.0) / 9223372036854775808.0;
    } while (d == -1.0 || d == 1.0);
    return d;
}

/* Returns an uniform pseudorandom integer between min and max, inclusive.
   Uses the exclusion method to ensure uniform distribution.
*/
static inline uint64_t prng_range(prng_state *prng, const uint64_t min, const uint64_t max)
{
    if (min != max) {
        const uint64_t  basis = (min < max) ? min : max;
        const uint64_t  range = (min < max) ? max-min : min-max;
        uint64_t        mask = range;
        uint64_t        u;

        /* In range, all bits up to the higest bit set in range, must be set. */
        mask |= mask >> 1;
        mask |= mask >> 2;
        mask |= mask >> 4;
        mask |= mask >> 8;
        mask |= mask >> 16;
        mask |= mask >> 32;

        /* In all cases, range <= mask < 2*range, so at worst case,
           (mask = 2*range-1), this excludes at most 50% of generated values,
           on average. */
        do {
            u = prng_u64(prng) & mask;
        } while (u > range);

        return u + basis;
    } else
        return min;
}

static inline void prng_seed(prng_state *prng)
{
#if _POSIX_TIMERS-0 > 0
    struct timespec  now;
#endif
    FILE            *src;

    /* Try /dev/urandom. */
    src = fopen(SEED_SOURCE, "r");
    if (src) {
        int  tries = 16;
        while (tries-->0) {
            if (fread(prng->state, sizeof prng->state, 1, src) != 1)
                break;
            if (prng->state[0]) {
                fclose(src);
                return;
            }
        }
        fclose(src);
    }

#if _POSIX_TIMERS-0 > 0
#if _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK-0 > 0
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == 0) {
        prng->state[0] = (uint64_t)((uint64_t)now.tv_sec * UINT64_C(60834327289))
                       ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)now.tv_nsec * UINT64_C(34958268769))
                       ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)getpid() * UINT64_C(2772668794075091))
                       ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)getppid() * UINT64_C(19455108437));
        if (prng->state[0])
            return;
    } else
#endif
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == 0) {
        prng->state[0] = (uint64_t)((uint64_t)now.tv_sec * UINT64_C(60834327289))
                       ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)now.tv_nsec * UINT64_C(34958268769))
                       ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)getpid() * UINT64_C(2772668794075091))
                       ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)getppid() * UINT64_C(19455108437));
        if (prng->state[0])
            return;
    }
#endif

    prng->state[0] = (uint64_t)((uint64_t)time(NULL) * UINT64_C(60834327289))
                   ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)clock() * UINT64_C(34958268769))
                   ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)getpid() * UINT64_C(2772668794075091))
                   ^ (uint64_t)((uint64_t)getppid() * UINT64_C(19455108437));
    if (!prng->state[0])
        prng->state[0] = (uint64_t)UINT64_C(16233055073);
}

#endif /* XORSHIFT64_H */
```

If it can seed the state from `SEED_SOURCE`, it is used as-is. Otherwise, if POSIX.1 `clock_gettime()` is available, it is used (`CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, if possible; otherwise `CLOCK_REALTIME`). Otherwise, time (`time(NULL)`), CPU time spent thus far (`clock()`), process ID (`getpid()`), and parent process ID (`getppid()`) are used to seed the state.

If you wanted the above to also run on Windows, you'd need to add a few `#ifndef _WIN32` guards, and either omit the process ID parts, or replace them with something else. (I don't use Windows myself, and cannot test such code, so I omitted such from above.)

The idea is that you can include the above file, and implement other pseudo-random number generators in the same format, and choose between them by simply including different files. (You can include multiple files, but you'll need to do some ugly `#define prng_state prng_somename_state`, `#include "somename.h"`, `#undef prng_state` hacking to ensure unique names for each.)

Here is an example of how to use the above:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xorshift64.h"

int main(void)
{
    prng_state  prng1, prng2;

    prng_seed(&prng1);
    prng_seed(&prng2);

    printf("Seed 1 = 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", prng1.state[0]);
    printf("Seed 2 = 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", prng2.state[0]);

    printf("After skipping 16 rounds:\n");
    prng_skip(&prng1, 16);
    prng_skip(&prng2, 16); 

    printf("Seed 1 = 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", prng1.state[0]);
    printf("Seed 2 = 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", prng2.state[0]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Obviously, initializing two PRNGs like this is problematic in the fallback case, because it basically relies on `clock()` yielding different values for consecutive calls (so expects each call to take at least 1 millisecond of CPU time).

However, even a small change in the seeds thus generated is sufficient to yield very different sequences. I like to generate and discard (skip) a number of initial values to ensure the generator state is well mixed:

```
Seed 1 = 0x8a62585b6e71f915
Seed 2 = 0x8a6259a84464e15f
After skipping 16 rounds:
Seed 1 = 0x9895f664c83ad25e
Seed 2 = 0xa3fd7359dd150e83
```

The header also implements `0 <= prng_u64() < 2**64`, `0 <= prng_one() < 1`, `-1 < prng_delta() < +1`, and `min <= prng_range(,min,max) <= max`, which should be uniform.

I use the above Xorshift64* variant for tasks where a lot of quite uniform pseudorandom numbers are needed, so the functions also tend to use the faster methods (like max. 50% average exclusion rate rather than 64-bit modulus operation, and so on) (of those that I know of).

Additionally, if you require repeatability, you can simply save a randomly-seeded `prng_state` structure (a single `uint64_t`), and load it later, to reproduce the exact same sequence. Just remember to only do the skipping (generate-and-discard) only after randomly seeding, not after loading a new seed from a file.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Converting rather copious comments into an answer.*</sup>

If two programs are started in the same second, they'll both have the same sequence of random numbers.

Consider whether you need to use a better random number generator than the `rand()`/`srand()` duo — that is usually only barely random (better than nothing, but not by a large margin). Do *NOT* use them for cryptography.

I asked about platform; you responded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Use `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` to get some random bytes for the seed. 
On many Unix-like platforms, there's a device `/dev/random` — on Linux, there's also a slightly lower-quality device `/dev/urandom` which won't block whereas `/dev/random` might. Systems such as macOS (BSD) have `/dev/urandom` as a synonym for `/dev/random` for Linux compatibility. You can open it and read 4 bytes (or the relevant number of bytes) of random data, and use that as a seed for the PRNG of your choice.

I often use the [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) set of functions because they are in POSIX and were in System V Unix. They're usually adequate for my needs.

Look at the manuals across platforms; there are often other random number generators. C++11 provides high-quality PRNG — the header [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) has a number of different ones, such as the MT 19937 (Mersenne Twister). MacOS Sierra (BSD) has `random(3)` and `arc4random(3)` as alternatives to `rand()` – as well as `drand48()` et al.

Another possibility on Linux is simply to keep a connection to `/dev/urandom` open, reading more bytes when you need them. However, that gives up any chance of replaying a random sequence. The PRNG systems have the merit of allowing you to replay the same sequence again by recording and setting the random seed that you use. By default, grab a seed from `/dev/urandom`, but if the user requests it, take a seed from the command line, and report the seed used (at least on request).